# ¿Se debería usar jQuery en "toda" aplicación HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

En [You may not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) (Tal vez no necesitas jQuery) se distinguen dos casos, el uso en la aplicación en sí y el de incluir jQuery como requisito de una librería. El caso del uso de jQuery como requisito de librería lo dejo fuera del alcance de esta pregunta porque de lo contrario quedaría como demasiado amplia. Esta pregunta está enfocada al uso de jQuery en la aplicación en sí.

En la referencia se sugiere usar jQuery siempre que sea posible, sin embargo, en Stack Overflow en inglés existen preguntas que solicitan respuestas usando JavaScript puro.

Hoy mismo aquí en Stack Overflow en español hay [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/82165/65) que al momento tiene dos respuestas una con jQuery y otra con JavaScript puro. Esta pregunta no trata sobre decir cuál de las dos respuestas es mejor sino de entender mejor las implicaciones de usar jQuery en una aplicación web.

Arriba mencioné que el caso de usar jQuery como requisito de una librería lo dejamos fuera de esta pregunta para que no sea demasiada amplia. También pido dejar fuera el compar jQuery con otras librerías similares.

Para que las respuestas puedan calificarse como objetivas y no basadas en opiniones, deben incluir argumentos metodológicos / técnicos fundamentados y centrados en la implicación de usar o no usar jQuery.

---

Traducción de la instroducción de You may not need jQuery

> jQuery y sus primos son grandes y por supuesto deben ser utilizados si
>   facilitan desarrollar de tu la aplicación.
>
> Sin embargo, si está desarrollando una librería, por favor toma un
>   momento para considerar si realmente necesitas jQuery como una
>   dependencia. Tal vez puedas incluir unas líneas de código de utilidad
>   y renunciar el requisito. Si sólo estás dirigiendo tu librería a los
>   navegadores más modernos, no necesitará nada más que con lo que el
>   navegador ya trae consigo.
>
> Por lo menos, asegúrate de que saber [qué está haciendo por tí jQuery](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LPaPA30bLUB_publLIMF0RlhdnPx_ePXm7oW02iiT6o),
>   y lo que no es. Algunos desarrolladores creen que jQuery nos protege
>   de un gran demonio de la incompatibilidad del navegador cuando, en
>   verdad, los navegadores posteriores a IE8 son bastante fáciles de
>   manejar por sí mismos.

Comment: Muy buena pregunta (Y), esperando cometarios

Comment: Personalmente creo que va a modas, si a la gente le enseñan jquery, creerán que es lo mejor hasta que aprendan otra cosa. Si aprenden javascript a secas raramente se verán con la necesidad de usar jquery, solo para solucionar problemas concretos, y solo si no lo saben solucionar ellos mismos.
El problemas es saber diferenciar cuando es útil, y nos ahorra código, y cuando es contraproducente y estamos matando moscas a cañonazos, no se si me explico.
A veces la gente parece que piense que jquery trabaja en una capa inferior o que hace "magia" en vez de verlo como una biblioteca de funciones.

Comment: @Rubén **jQuery** realmente es muy utilizado, es difícil poder ver un sitio que no este vinculado o que no tenga ningún tipo de vinculación con **jQuery.** Yo pienso en lo personal que utilizar `javascript` puro es demasiado código, demasiado extenso... En `jQuery` se puede crear una gran variedad de utilidad, aunque a de a poco los estilos `CSS` esta abarcando de a poco por ejemplo crear un: **Slider, animación** entre otros... pero a pesar de querer abarcar existe mucho código de por medio. Sobre la utilización depende mucho sobre la aplicación web, creo que sí es posible.

Comment: @Mick no, si tu enfoque es los navegadores modernos el código es incluso más simple que utilizando jQuery y sus chain messages. Yo uso JavaScript puro utilizando las especificaciones de la W3C si un navegador sigue dichas especificaciones (que deben hacerlo) entonces la portabilidad del código está garantizada, y de lo contrario (que es minoría) no importa, porque no es mi objetivo hacerlo portable para navegadores específicos.

Comment: @J.Mick: El que jQuery es muy utilizado lo tengo muy claro pero no tenía claro el motivo ni la justificación de que una nueva aplicación tenga que ser así. En cuanto a lo de si es difícil  de ver un sitio que no tenga ningún tipo de vinculación con jQuery me parece que no es así. Con una herramienta como [Wappalyzer](https://wappalyzer.com/) me parece que es muy fácil.

Comment: Hay un solo caso actualmente por el cual tengo que seguir usando JQuery en ocasiones: Cuando trabajo en equipo (Y dependiendo del equipo, claro). Hay gente que se reusa a aprender a usar javascript por el demonio atado a su pasado. Por lo tanto, hay que usar JQuery para que esas personas puedan entender y trabajar en tu código. Sin embargo, no es algo que uno deba alentar...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

La respuesta es **NO**. Cuando usas una librería o framework, la pregunta que te viene a la cabeza es:

> ¿**Realmente** lo necesito?

Obviamente, decenas de razones pasan por tu cabeza y al final, lo que te motiva a elegir entre uno u otro son **las necesidades** que tengas. Cuando nació [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), la manera de desarrollar en JavaScript para propósitos *multiplataforma* era literalmente una pesadilla, tenías que tener muchas cosas en cuenta y hacer un código para cada navegador en la mayoría de los casos. Se puede decir que, [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) nació como un *polyfill* para IE6.

Desde aquella época las cosas han cambiado mucho; el comité encargado de la especificación empezó a trabajar, la comunidad empezó a crear muchas librerías y frameworks cada vez mejores; se empezó a popularizar nuevos conceptos como el *Virtual DOM*, programación *reactiva*, *data binding*, etc.

En mi opinión, [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) para desarrollo web moderno a escala profesional ha quedado totalmente obsoleto; algunas personas no estarán de acuerdo, otros sí. Pienso que hoy en día manejar el DOM directamente ya no es necesario; de hecho, abusar de esto puede reflejarse negativamente en el rendimiento de tu aplicación. Con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) haces esto **exahustivamente** por que para esto fue creado y, si ya de por sí manipular demasiado el DOM puede significar un mal rendimiento, **usando jQuery reduces las ops/s de manera brutal**. En la actualidad, han aparecido nuevas técnicas que ofrecen mejores soluciones que vale la pena utilizar. La evolución de un ecosistema de tecnologías siempre mejora lo ya existente.

> ¿Es **necesario** usar una librería como [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) para mi proyecto?

La respuesta dependerá de la escala del proyecto; para proyectos pequeños, [es6](/questions/tagged/es6) y superior basta y sobra; para proyectos a mediana y grande escala es mejor confiar en un framework eficiente y que signifique menos esfuerzo/tiempo de desarrollo y un modelo de desarollo más flexible.

> ¿Realmente es [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) **la mejor opción** para lo que necesito?

La respuesta puede contestarse con otra pregunta: ¿Existen **mejores** alternativas que me permitan hacer lo mismo de manera más **eficiente** y **dinámica**?

---

Yo creo que usar [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) depende además, del nivel de experiencia que tengas con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript); obviamente para un programador netamente backend, usar [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) será mucho más fácil que usar [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) o [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) con [redux](/questions/tagged/redux); sin embargo, si nos ceñimos a una realidad objetiva, es mejor si, en lo posible, usamos alternativas que significen una mayor productividad y nos provean de mayores beneficios, como calidad del código, eficiencia, escalabilidad, etc.

Lo cierto es que **el desarrollo frontend ha evolucionado considerablemente** y han aparecido **nuevas soluciones a viejos problemas**, soluciones más eficientes, más compactas, más concisas; es por esto que han nacido frameworks que están revolucionando el desarrollo frontend, como son [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) o [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js).

Como se suele decir en este mundillo... **Usa la herramienta correcta para el trabajo correcto**.

Comment: Gustavo-Sama :):):)

Answer (score 6):

Hay varios conflictos en utilizar `jQuery` entre ellos :

1. Dependencia innecesaria ["Realmente necesito `jQuery`?"](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

   > Si está desarrollando una biblioteca por otro lado, por favor tome un momento para considerar si realmente necesita jQuery como dependencia. Tal vez usted puede incluir algunas líneas útiles de código, y olvidarse de la dependencia. Si su enfoque es principalmente navegadores modernos, es posible que no necesite nada más que lo que el navegador ofrece.
2. Seguridad, existen docenas de ataques utilizando [un falso `jQuery`](https://blog.avast.com/wordpress-and-joomla-users-get-hacked-be-aware-of-fake-jquery)

   > Los Hackers utilizan la biblioteca popular de Javascript jQuery para inyectar código malicioso en sitios suministrados por WordPress y Joomla.
3. Perfomance, si bien es cierto que jQuery es rápido, la bifurcación de código y detección de funcionalidades resultan en penalizaciones, ni hablar a los wrappers acerca de funcionalides DOM2, donde el stack trace es más amplio 
   [image: benchmark]

   https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/22
4. Penalización en la carga de la página, si utilizas una version estable y pequeña como lo es `jQuery 1.7`, su versión minificada pesa solamente `1Kib` mientras que `jQuery 3.0` pesa `87Kib`! super mario bros pesó tan solo `31Kib`! 3 veces menos que `jQuery 3.0`... esos `87Kib` aún deben ser analizados e interpretados, lo que resulta en un atrazo en la carga de la página
5. Consumo extra de Datos (solo para dispositivos móviles)
   Los móviles generalmente utilizan `planes de datos` ofrecidos por las compañías de servicios telefónicos, estos `planes` tienen *cobro por servicio*, así que tu página al cargar `jQuery 3.0` está gastando innecesariamente dichos recursos, si el usuario usa un navegador sin un sistema de `caché` (absurdo hoy en día, pero imaginense que exista alguno), por cada página de tu web, estaría gastando `87Kib` , es decir que si tu usario entra y sale de la página unas `1024` veces habrá consumido `87 Mib` sólo en cargar `jQuery` ...
6. Curva extra de aprendizaje
7. Sintáxis azucarada, la sintáxis azucarada de `jQuery` con `$(TODO)` empeora la legibilidad del código, sin hablar del uso absurdo y desmedido de funciones anónimas para todo.

En general, lo mejor es NO utilizar jQuery, y de usarlo, lo mejor es solo extraer los módulos necesarios

> Lo malo de la programación orientada a objetos, es que si quieres una banana, te traes la banana, el gorila, y la jungla entera - Joe Armstrong

Comment: como referencia podrias traducir los textos en ingles? el sitio es en español ;)

Comment: ya he actualizado con una traducción parafraseada.

Answer (score 2):

Para completar las respuestas anteriores, he de añadir que a día de hoy (Abril 2018), la popularidad de otros frameworks como Angular, React, Vue... y de herramientas como Typescript, WebPack y Babel.js ha provocado que no necesitemos acceder al DOM de la manera clásica o que no tengamos que preocuparnos por las incompatibilidades entre distintos navegadores y el estándar de la W3C.

De hecho, mezclar Angular o React con jQuery es totalmente contraproducente porque los ciclos de vida de los componentes son manejados de un modo muy distinto por estos frameworks y la potencial injerencia de jQuery no hace sino complicar la vida a cualquier desarrollador.

jQuery ha pasado de ser **LA librería** a ser una opción más en un mundo que evoluciona a una velocidad enorme.