# cual es la diferencia entre usar $().val() y document.getElementById().value; en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

pues estoy un poco confundido sobre como obtener el valor de los campos en Javascript, he visto que muchas veces se obtiene usando el código:

```
document.getElementById("elemento").value;
```

y otras usando el código:

```
$(elemento).val()
```

**¿cual es la diferencia?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Son dos formas de hacer lo mismo.

**$** es el nombre de variable que hace referencia al objeto document en jQuery, un **librería** de JavaScript muy popular. La documentación oficial de jQuery está en https://jquery.com/

**document** es una variable que nativa que hace referencia al objeto document.

El **objeto document** tiene la finalidad de manejar en memoria el contenido de la página web cargada en el navegador. Lo que rige sus características se conoce como Modelo del Objeto Documento, en inglés Document Object Model o DOM. No forma de parte de la especificación ECMAScript que es el estándar para especificar cómo los motores de JavaScript deben de manejar las secuencias de comando (scripts) realizadas con este lenguaje, sino que tiene su propio estándar publicado por el W3C.

La dirección web de la ECMAScript es http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/

La dirección web sobre el DOM es https://www.w3.org/DOM/

jQuery surgió cuando JavaScript carecía de formas sencillas de realizar operaciones con el DOM sin embargo a lo largo de los años ha mejorado así como también lo ha hecho jQuery, sin embargo, han surgido otros **librerías** y **frameworks** que ofrecen cosas similares. Los **frameworks** son herramientas que le pueden ayudar a un programador a ser más eficiente pero como toda herramienta, debe escogerse la adecuada para la tarea.

Relacionado
[¿Se debería usar jQuery en "toda" aplicación HTML/CSS/JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/82254/65)

Comment: Observacion: [jquery es una libreria, no un framework](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: El que sea una librería no excluye el que sea un framework. ¿podrías explicar porque piensas que no es un framework?

Comment: Cite la documentación oficial. Por eso me basó en que no es un framework. O me pierdo de algo?

Comment: Sí, te pierdes de varias cosas, pero para no hacer polémica aquí y prevenir que se descarrile este hilo, voy a poner lo que dice la documentación oficial

Comment: No se preocupe no pasa nada. Era sólo una observación.

Comment: Hola @Rubén, normalmente es considerada una librería, puedes encontrar suficiente información en la red acerca de esta polémica (que viene de hace mucho), [aquí tienes un enlace en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062775/is-jquery-a-javascript-library-or-framework).

Comment: @ElChiniNet: A eso me refería cno que Einer se perdía de algo :D

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia es que el código sin *jQuery* es de una sola línea, mientras que con *jQuery* son muchas líneas, y es un código rebuscado que intenta funcionar en todos los navegadores.

Sin *jQuery*:

```
document.getElementById().value;
```

Para obtener el código de la función `val` en *jQuery*, se hace lo siguiente, usando la versión no comprimida de *jQuery* llamada *slim*, en su [sección de descargas](http://jquery.com/download/):

```js
console.log($().val+"")
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"></script>
```

La respuesta que obtuve fue la siguiente:

```
function val( value ) {
    var hooks, ret, isFunction,
        elem = this[ 0 ];

    if ( !arguments.length ) {
        if ( elem ) {
            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] ||
                jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

            if ( hooks &&
                "get" in hooks &&
                ( ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" ) ) !== undefined
            ) {
                return ret;
            }

            ret = elem.value;

            // Handle most common string cases
            if ( typeof ret === "string" ) {
                return ret.replace( rreturn, "" );
            }

            // Handle cases where value is null/undef or number
            return ret == null ? "" : ret;
        }

        return;
    }

    isFunction = jQuery.isFunction( value );

    return this.each( function( i ) {
        var val;

        if ( this.nodeType !== 1 ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( isFunction ) {
            val = value.call( this, i, jQuery( this ).val() );
        } else {
            val = value;
        }

        // Treat null/undefined as ""; convert numbers to string
        if ( val == null ) {
            val = "";

        } else if ( typeof val === "number" ) {
            val += "";

        } else if ( Array.isArray( val ) ) {
            val = jQuery.map( val, function( value ) {
                return value == null ? "" : value + "";
            } );
        }

        hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ this.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ this.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

        // If set returns undefined, fall back to normal setting
        if ( !hooks || !( "set" in hooks ) || hooks.set( this, val, "value" ) === undefined ) {
            this.value = val;
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: Soy muy partidario de sustentar respuestas apoyándose en el código base que demuestra la diferencia, en este caso el de jQuery, sin embargo creo que faltó una pequeña explicación de lo que hace (o intenta hacer) dicho código. +1

Answer (score 1):

cuando usas `$` estas haciendo referencia a [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) que es una biblioteca  de JavaScript, su principal uso es el de selector, que es el ejemplo que das, pero tiene muchos más usos, como animaciones, peticiones ajax más sencillas y mucho más. Para más información visita la [página principal](https://jquery.com/).
Cuando usas `document.getElementById("elemento")` estas usando la forma nativa de javascript para referenciar un elemento por id. En JQuery es:

```
var elemento = $('#id'); //referencia por id
var elemento = $('p'); //referencia por tipo, en este caso todas las etiquetas p
var elemento = $('.clase'); //referencia por clase, todas las etiquetas 
// que tengan la clase 'clase' estarán contenidas dentro de la variable elemento
```

Answer (score 1):

Hacen lo mismo, como dice Reinier $ hace referencia a Jquery mientras que GetElementById es el método nativo de Javascript.

te recuerdo que Jquery está escrito en Javascript por lo que, traer el valor de las dos formas es valido.

```js
function myfunction(){
  var valor = document.getElementById('box').value;
  alert(valor);
}


$(function(){

  $(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
  var valor = $('#box').val();
  alert(valor);
  });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="text" id="box" value="prueba">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Prueba con Jquery">
  <input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="Prueba con Javascript">
```

Answer (score -1):

Como todos han expresado, `.val()` y `.value` es lo mismo pero queria agregar algo.

La razon por la que se utiliza `.val()` sobre `.value` es para asegurarse de que funcione en todos los navegadores. Por ejemplo `.innerHtml` no funcionaba igual en todos los navegadores pero jquery nos lo soluciono con `.html()`, haciendo todo el trabajo sucio de hacer que funcione segun el navegador y asi dandos un unico metodo para todos los navegadores(desktop y smartphone). Nos da API facil para manipular el DOM.