# Dar color con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo esta tabla:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Lo que me gustaría es darle color, **NO** con CSS o HTML, ya que se usarlos, pero no se usar **JavaScript** por eso quiero darle color por medio de ese lenguaje, por ejemplo que las filas sean de color verde y el encabezado de color rojo.

Comment: Hola Reinos, podrías explicar porque exactamente **no con CSS**?

Comment: Hola, @CarlosMuñoz  me refiero que en mi tabla pueda darle color a las filas y columnas pero sin necesidad de usar CSS. Que sea con puro codigo JavaScript...
Saludos

Comment: Como mera curiosidad, ¿Por qué no quieres usar CSS? Antes de entrar en las broncas de usar JS para hacer tus estilos...

Comment: Precisamente esa es mi pregunta porque con Javascript y no con CSS? Si los colores son estáticos no hay necesidad de usar JavaScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con JS puedes decir que todas las cabeceras `th` sean con fondo rojo  y las celdas `td` sean verdes. Supongo que no queriendo usar CSS te refieras a no modificar el archivo `.css` pero **aun con JS** tienes que usar los estilos `css`.

Coges todos los elemenentos `td` o `th` con `getElementsByTagName` e iteras por ellos.

Si lo que quieres no es el color de fondo, si no el color de letra, no es `backgroundColor` sino `color`.

```js
var ths = document.getElementsByTagName("th");

for (var i = 0; i < ths.length; i++) {

  ths[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";

}

var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {

  tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";

}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola, el OP no ha especificado que usa jQuery ni en el contenido del post ni en las etiquetas, por lo que las respuestas se esperan en javascript puro

Comment: Hola @user2930137. Yo lo interpreto al revés. Jquery **es** javascript. y a menos que diga que no quiere nada de librerias externas, por qué no?

Comment: De hecho @user2930137 me entendio, quiero Javascript puro..
Saludos

Comment: @ReinosRic cachis... bueno, estoy modificandolo ahaha

Comment: Orales, gracias, yo lo estaba haciendo por clases, osea que por ejemplo: **<td class= green1>**, je je no se si me de a entender, pero con el tuyo no tienes la necesidad de crearlos, me encanto

Comment: @ReinosRic bueno, tu verás como lo quieres hahah date cuenta de lo mucho que cambia usando JS puro o con jQuery... consideralo usar porque simplifica mucho la vida! hahah un saludo

Comment: @lois6b, es simple, si en las etiquetas o en el contenido el OP no indica cierta tecnología entonces normalmente no habría porqué incluirla en una respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: Si el OP busca aprender el lenguaje **es mucho mejor ir con JavaScript puro**, sin frameworks ni bibliotecas; esto le permitirá aprender el core del lenguaje y saber hacer las cosas por su cuenta para no depender siempre de terceros.

Comment: No es indispensable usar CSS. Existen atributos HTML para lograr lo que el OP está buscando.

Comment: Hola, soy principiante, y me puse a estudiar por mi propia cuenta JavaScript, se que es Jquery. Pero tengo el problema que solo se DISEÑAR EN HTML Y CSS, mas no se ni la pisca de lo básico de JavaScript. Gracias y saludos

Comment: @lois6b: No lleves al OP al lado oscuro de JavaScript :P Referencia [¿Se debería usar jQuery en “toda” aplicación HTML/CSS/JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/82254/65)

Answer (score 3):

En javascript puro,

Usando `elemento.getElementsByTagName(tag)` para obtener la lista de los tag en este caso son **th** y **td**

Esto me devuelve un array de todos los tag en el documento, entonces para agregarselo a todos, itero en estos con un ciclo for y le agrego el color con el metodo `setAttribute(atributo,valor)`

Si quieres que NO, se aplique a toda el documento, sino solo un div en donde se encuentren esos tag, pues envez de hacer `document..getElementsByTagName(tag)`, reemplazas el `'document'` por tu elemento, por ejemplo:

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("miDiv");


var titulos = div1.getElementsByTagName("TH");
 var titulos2 = div1.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  var t1 = titulos.length,t2=titulos2.length;
 
 for(var i=0;i<t1;i++) {
 titulos[i].setAttribute('style','color: red');
 }
  for(var i=0;i<t2;i++) {
 titulos2[i].setAttribute('style','color: green');
 }
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="miDiv">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="miDiv2">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

***Y en lo que respecta a tu codigo aqui esta:***

```js
var titulos = document.getElementsByTagName("TH");
 var titulos2 = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  var t1 = titulos.length,t2=titulos2.length;
 
 for(var i=0;i<t1;i++) {
 titulos[i].setAttribute('style','color: red');
 }
  for(var i=0;i<t2;i++) {
 titulos2[i].setAttribute('style','color: green');
 }
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***OJO: Es una bien sabido, que mejora el rendimiento guardar el .length en una variable externa***

Comment: Gracias, pero por ejemplo, si quiero que la palabra john este de color rojo como lo modificaría, por , por que tengo entendido que son bidireccionales no?

Comment: ¿Por qué cargas jQuery en uno de los snippets? No tiene sentido, por un lado porque ese snippet no hace uso de jQuery, por otro lado, la pregunta no hace mención alguna de jQuery.

Comment: y por otro lado, no afecta en nada cargar jquery, ni siquiera tu critica es constructiva

Comment: No me llegó notificación de tu comentario. Favor de revisar [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/65). En relación a que no afecta en nada, estas equivocado, pero parece que estás a la defensiva y por ende poco receptivo. Si tu actitud cambia avísame o mejor aún, publica una pregunta sobre el efecto de cargar una librería que no se ocupa, así tendrías oportunidad de recibir el punto de vista de alguien más.

Answer (score 1):

En [Primeros pasos en la Web](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web) se explica el propósito moderno de incluir HTML, CSS y JavaScript cuando se desarrolla una página web.

Si no hay un motivo para hacer dinámica una página web y no se desea usar CSS, entonces, podríamos decir que lo que estás buscando se puede lograr usando "HTML puro".

A continuación se presenta el caso usar el atributo `bgcolor` para dar color a las filas, rojo para el encabezado, verde para las demás, dejando el CSS original intacto.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr bgcolor="red">
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="green">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="green">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="green">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No veo porque utilizas HTML, cual sea el motivo, claramente dijo NO con CSS o HTML, se asume que si dice eso, es porque YA SABE hacerlo en html o css

Comment: @EduardoSebastian: Mi respuesta es previa la revisión en la que el OP agregó que no quiere usar HMTL puro. Luego veré si la actualizo o la elimino.